# Wierd result in sprintf in esp-idf esp32-c6

Tags: printf, esp-idf

sprintf function in ESP32-C6 seems wierd ...

Any ideas....

Regards..

/Stefan

This string:

```
    sprintf(Json_str," {\"time\":%lld,\"value\":%4.2f,\"nodename\":\"ESP32_TEST\",\"nodelocation\":\"home\"} ",timer,temperature);
```

results in vscode / debugger watching the Json_Str:

" {"time":1687183452,"value":26.80,"nodename":"ESP32_TEST","nodelocation":"home"} \000\377\377;\000\000\000\n\000\000\000372216\001@\377\377\377\377;\000\000\000\n\000\000\000276216\001@\377\377\377\377;\000\000\000376\377\377\377^222\001@245245245245245245245245\000\000\000\000306252\200@"

when it should be:

{"time":1687184884,"value":26.60,"nodename":"ESP32_TEST","nodelocation":"home"}

Comment: Can you share a minimal reproduciable example, especially the definition of `Json_str`